# Virtual Light Sensor for Windows 8 Desktop

Tags: windows-8, sensors, light

I want to develop a desktop application (C#) with support for light sensors but I dont have a real light sensor, Is there a way to install a "Virtual Ambient Light Sensor" on Windows 8?

Comment: Is there some problem writing a simulator for one?

Comment: Do you mean to write my own virtual sensor? I dont know how to doit, I found a virtual light sensor for windows 7 http://fusionovation.com/post/2009/05/14/more-exploration-of-the-windows-7-sensor-and-location-api.aspx but it doesnt work on Windows 8

Comment: Simulation at the device driver level seems like overkill. Can't you just simulate in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why can't you simply mock the light sensor to test your app? See the [lightsensor api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor), further Scott Hanselman has already blogged some examples on [how to access RT API from the Desktop Ap](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx). With the above two you can mock, test and use the light sensor directly in your app.